# Construct a grammar for $\{a^n(bc)^m : m,n \ge 1, m < n/2\}$

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm new to writing languages in context-free or regular grammar, so I'm struggling how to do this one. It is a bit more complicated that simpler ones I've practiced doing. The problem is to construct a grammar for the following language:

$$\{a^n (bc)^m \in \{a, b, c\}^* \mid m, n \ge 1 \land m < n/2\}$$

An explanation of how to start and go through the language would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = n'+1$, $m = m'+1$. Then $m < n/2$ translates to $n'+ 1 > 2(m+1)$, i.e. $n' \geq 2m'+2$. Therefore we can write the language as
$$
\{ a^{1+2m'+2+k}(bc)^{1+m'} : m',k \geq 0 \} =
\{ a^3 a^k (a^2)^{m'} (bc)^{m'} bc : m',k \geq 0 \}.
$$
You take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm not sure how to approach where a has two different exponent variable. I know for example L = {aa(a^n) : n >= 0}, would have S --> aA | A --> aA, but I'm not sure how to do {(a^n)a^m. Also, for bc would you keep them together, such as L = {a(bc)^n : n >= 0} would have grammar S --> aC | C --> bc. My questions might have trivial answers, but I'm just not 100% confident in it.

Comment: I suggest spending a few hours on the problem. In particular, I'm not planning to give any more hints.